# Copy data from PostgreSQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, groovy

I have source table in PostgreSQL and and target table in SQL Server. I am using Groovy script for copying data.

I'm trying to implement batch loading but it's not working, here is my sample code.

Please let me know if any one has any idea.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql_orig = Sql.newInstance( )
def sql_dest =  Sql.newInstance( )

batchSize=20

sql_dest.withBatch( batchSize, "insert into TABLE_DESTINO(a,b,c) values(?,?,?)"){ ps->  

   sql_orig.eachRow "select a,b,c from TABLE_ORIGEN",{ row ->   

    ps.addBatch(row) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a Linked Server in SQL Server, then just doing a straight `INSERT YourTable ... SELECT ... FROM PostgresServer.YourDB..Table`. Should be far faster. Another option is to use SSIS or similar

Comment: but i have source table sitting in PostgreSQL not in SQL server

Comment: Yes and you create a Linked Server to Postgres so you can query it directly from SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: got it. thanks for your quick reply..  is it good for moving around 9 millions records  with linked server.. or is it performance is slow.